# Lookup and add value to new column python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV with 2 columns and I need to create a lookup table within pandas that will add a column according to the some of the values of that row. Example:

```
DIMENSION    ACCOUNT NAME
Tax          Tiger Beta
Config       Tiger Alpha
S3           Lion Alpha
Lambda       Tiger Cigna
Glacier      Beta - Lion
```

What I want to add:

```
DIMENSION    ACCOUNT NAME    ADDED_COLUMN1     ADDED_COLUMN2    ADDED_COLUMN3
Tax          Tiger Beta        Other             Tiger_Group      Beta
Config       Tiger Alpha       Other             Tiger_Group      Alpha
S3           Lion Alpha        VM                Lion_Group       Alpha
Lambda       Tiger Cigna       Other             Tiger_Group      Cigna
Glacier      Beta - Lion       VM                Lion_Group       Beta
Snowball     Monkey Alpha       Disk             Monkey_Group     Alpha
```

Basically I need it to strip some of the parts of the Account Name and add it to a new column and I need ADDED_COLUMN1 to be according to the DIMENSION (I choose which one is VM, which one is Disk, which one is Other).

What I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

#turn the csv to a pandas dataframe
data_1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')


data_1['ADDED_COLUMN1'] = np.where(data_1.DIMENSION.isin(['S3', 'Glacier']), 
'VM', 'Other')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
rank = {"Alpha", "Beta","Cigna"}
Animal = {"Tiger", "Lion"}

def Lookup1(x):
    df_words = set(x.split(' '))
    extract_words =  rank.intersection(df_words)
    return ', '.join(extract_words)

def Lookup2(x):
    df_words = set(x.split(' '))
    extract_words =  Animal.intersection(df_words)
    return ', '.join(extract_words)



df['ADDED_COLUMN3'] = df['ACCOUNT NAME'].apply(Lookup1)
df['ADDED_COLUMN1'] = df['ACCOUNT NAME'].apply(Lookup2)
df['ADDED_COLUMN1'] =  df['ADDED_COLUMN1'] +'_Group'
```

which returns

```
 DIMENSION ACCOUNT NAME ADDED_COLUMN3 ADDED_COLUMN1
0       Tax   Tiger Beta          Beta   Tiger_Group
1    Config  Tiger Alpha         Alpha   Tiger_Group
2        S3   Lion Alpha         Alpha    Lion_Group
3    Lambda  Tiger Cigna         Cigna   Tiger_Group
4   Glacier  Beta - Lion          Beta    Lion_Group
```